# Java Streams how do i check for null values and send message while mapping for a new list

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist, java-8, java-stream

So I'm basically trying to figure out if there is a way to avoid having the same code twice and also get key in the place where I'm getting the syntax error.

```
List<String> listOfKeys = new ArrayList<>(
    Arrays.asList("key1", "key2", "key3", "key4", "key5"));
String path = "something.something.";

listOfKeys.stream()
    .map(key -> path + key)
    .map(getConfig()::getString)
    .forEach(value -> { 
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) 
            getLogger().info(key + " is empty"); 
    }); 

List<String> listOfValue = listOfKeys.stream()
    .map(key -> path + key)
    .map(getConfig()::getString)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I know that **key** in the log method is syntax error but I'm wondering how would I be able to access the **key** in that point and send the message with the **key** that had the null value?
Also is it possible to do all of it while creating the `listOfValues` in the second stream?

Comment: There also is `Objects.toString()`, where with a second argument it allows you to put an empty string if null. Not sure if that would help your predicament too. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html - I was thinking you could use that in the mapping process to accommodate nulls perhaps.

Comment: If I were you, will go with `forEach` loop. `for (String key : listOfKeys) {
            String value = getConfig().getString(String.format("%s%s", path, key));
            listOfValue.add(value);
            if (value == null || value.isEmpty())
                getLogger().info(key + " is empty");
        }` IMO use of conditions to log something is not best practice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `peek`. It evaluates a block of code and continues streaming:

```
List<String> listOfValue = listOfKeys.stream()
    .map(key -> path + key)
    .map(getConfig()::getString)
    .peek(value -> { 
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) 
            getLogger().info(key + " is empty"); 
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you want to use the key in logging, you can use `Map.Entry`:

```
List<String> listOfValue = listOfKeys.stream()
    .map(key -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(key, getConfig().getString(path + key))
    .peek(entry -> { 
        if (entry.getValue() == null || entry.getValue().isEmpty()) 
            getLogger().info(entry.getKey() + " is empty"); 
    })
    .map(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Yes, that solves one problem out of two, do you maybe know how would i get key for the log message?

Comment: Unless you are using this  to debug your code you should probably find an alternative.  From the Java API *This method exists mainly to support debugging, where you want to see the elements as they flow past a certain point in a pipeline*

Comment: @WJS I was just playing around with streams trying to get a better understanding on how they work. Thanks for the tip.